# Question tags not being populated in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, database, null

I'm working on an application that involves handling questions and tags. I've made a `QuestionService` class that provides methods for creating and retrieving questions, as well as a `QuestionMapper` class that handles the mapping between the `Question` entity and the `QuestionDto` DTO.

However, I'm running into an issue where the tags associated with a question are not being populated correctly. When I create a new question, the tags are saved correctly in the database, but when I retrieve the question, the tags are returned as an emplty set.

Here's the code for my `Question` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User author;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "questions_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "question_image_urls", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"))
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private List<String> imageUrls;

    @Column(name = "date_published")
    private LocalDateTime datePublished;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.datePublished = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my `QuestionService` class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuestionService {
    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository;
    private final QuestionMapper questionMapper;

    public ResponseEntity createQuestion(QuestionDto data) {
        Question question = questionMapper.toEntity(data);
        questionRepository.save(question);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(MessageResponse.from("The question has been created successfully!"));
    }

    public ResponseEntity> getAllQuestions() {
        List questions = questionRepository.findAll();
        List questionDtos = questionMapper.toDto(questions);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(questionDtos);
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my `QuestionMapper` class:

```
@Component
public class QuestionMapper {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final TagRepository tagRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    public QuestionMapper(ModelMapper modelMapper, TagRepository tagRepository,
                          UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.tagRepository = tagRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public QuestionDto toDto(Question question) {
        QuestionDto questionDto = modelMapper.map(question, QuestionDto.class);

        questionDto.setAuthorId(question.getAuthor().getId());

        Set<Long> tagIds = question.getTags().stream()
                .map(Tag::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        questionDto.setTagIds(tagIds);


        return questionDto;
    }

    public List<QuestionDto> toDto(List<Question> questions) {
        return questions.stream()
                .map(this::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Question toEntity(QuestionDto questionDto) {
        Question question = modelMapper.map(questionDto, Question.class);

        question.setAuthor(findById(userRepository, questionDto.getAuthorId()));

        if (questionDto.getTagIds() != null) {
            question.setTags(questionDto.getTagIds().stream()
                    .map(id -> findById(tagRepository, id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        }

        return question;
    }

    public Question toEntity(QuestionDto questionDto, Question question) {
        modelMapper.map(questionDto, question);

        question.setAuthor(findById(userRepository, questionDto.getAuthorId()));

        if (questionDto.getTagIds() != null) {
            question.setTags(questionDto.getTagIds().stream()
                    .map(id -> findById(tagRepository, id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        }
        return question;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my `Tag` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Question> questions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}
```

This has been bugging me from days. I have tried to resolve it myself but non of the methods i tried seem to make any difference.

Comment: You mentioned that `tags` are persisted correctly in the db, but what about the relationship between `question` and `tag`? JPA should automatically create a `questions_tags` table with appropriate relationships.

I am just wondering if you can set a breakpoint to `questions.findAll()` and see if list of `questions_tags` is present. Perhaps, set `CascadeType.ALL` in the `Question` class

I think my gut feeling is telling me that the way questions and tags are persisted may not have the relationships established.